# decorator argument: unable to access instance attribute

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator

### Context

class `MyMockClient` below has two methods:

- `push_log`: pushes one `log` from list `self.logs` and pops it
- `push_event`: pushes one `event` from list `self.events` and pops it

Both methods are decorated using `__iterate_pushes` which essentially
iterate push_event and push_log until their respective lists are entirely popped
AND in the full program applies some extra logics (e.g. tracks how many objects were pushed).

### Problem

The decorator `__iterate_pushes` needs to access `self.logs` and `self.events`.
However, it does not seem to work. In the example below, you can see that the program fails because self.logs is not available when the function is defined.

Any idea how to solve this?

### Example

```
class MyMockClient:
    def __init__(self, logs, events):
        self.logs = logs
        self.events = events

    def __iterate_pushes(self, obj):
        """
        Decorate function to iterate the 'pushes' until
        the lists are entirely popped.
        """
        def outer_wrapper(self, decorated_func):
            def inner_wrapper(self):
                responses = []
                print(f"len: {len(obj)}")
                while len(obj) > 0: # iterate until list is entirely popped
                    response = decorated_func() # when executed, it pops the first item
                    responses.append(response)
                    print(f"len: {len(obj)}")
                return responses

            return inner_wrapper

        return outer_wrapper
        
    @__iterate_pushes(obj = self.logs)
    def push_log(self):
        # Send first log and pops it if successful
        log = self.logs[0]
        print(log, "some extra logics for logs")
        response = "OK" # let's assume API call is OK
        if response == "OK":
            self.logs.pop(0)
        return response
    
    @__iterate_pushes(obj = self.events)    
    def push_event(self):
        # Send first event and pops it if successful
        event = self.events[0]
        print(event, "some extra logics for events")
        response = "OK" # let's assume API call is OK
        if response == "OK":
            self.events.pop(0)
        return response

my_mock_client = MyMockClient(
    logs = [1, 2, 3],
    events = [4, 5, 6]
)

my_mock_client.push_log()
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 class MyMockClient:
      2     def __init__(self, logs, events):
      3         self.logs = logs

Cell In[2], line 25, in MyMockClient()
     21         return inner_wrapper
     23     return outer_wrapper
---> 25 @__iterate_pushes(obj = self.logs)
     26 def push_log(self):
     27     # Send first log and pops it if successful
     28     log = self.logs[0]
     29     print(log, "some extra logics for logs")

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: `self` is not defined in the scope of the class body, hence the `NameError`.  `self` is only defined within method bodies and signatures, where it represents the instance on which the method is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my opinion, but I believe you are using decorator when it shouldn't be used. This is not intuitive and it implicitly changes the logic and signature of the decorated methods (e.x. instead of returning a single `response` it makes the method return a list of `response`s). I'd suggest making a simple "private" method instead that you'd call from inside of `push_log` and `push_event`:

```
class MyMockClient:
    def __init__(self, logs, events):
        self.logs = logs
        self.events = events

    def _iterate_pushes(self, obj):
        responses = []
        print(f"len: {len(obj)}")
        while len(obj) > 0:  # iterate until list is entirely popped
            response = obj.pop(0)  # when executed, it pops the first item
            responses.append(response)
            print(f"len: {len(obj)}")
        return responses

    def push_log(self):
        # Send first log and pops it if successful
        log = self.logs[0]
        print(log, "some extra logics for logs")
        
        return self._iterate_pushes(self.logs)

    def push_event(self):
        # Send first event and pops it if successful
        event = self.events[0]
        print(event, "some extra logics for events")
        
        return self._iterate_pushes(self.events)
```

---

#### Answer to your question (don't recommend):

Use `getattr` and pass a field name:

```
class MyMockClient:
    ...
    def __iterate_pushes(self, obj_name):
        """
        Decorate function to iterate the 'pushes' until
        the lists are entirely popped.
        """
        def outer_wrapper(self, decorated_func):
            def inner_wrapper(self):
                responses = []
                obj = getattr(self, obj_name)
                ...
                return responses

            return inner_wrapper

        return outer_wrapper

    @__iterate_pushes(obj_name='logs')
    def push_log(self):
        ...
        return response

    @__iterate_pushes(obj_name='events')
    def push_event(self):
        ...
        return response
```

Comment: Thank you. First answer is perfectly clean.
For second answer, clear it is not recommended. However, interesting to learn about `getattr`.

Comment: Testing the first answer, the output of the two solutions is different. So it is not just a matter of form but also output:
while the "decorator solution" executes the function push_log for each item in the list, the "first answer" executes the function push_log only once.